# Is it possible to query Pandas IntervalIndex with Intervals

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, intervals

I was just wondering whether there is a way to query a Pandas IntervalIndex with an Interval (or range), eventually returning all Intervals in the IntervalIndex that overlap with the queried Interval.

For instance given an IntervalIndex `idx`:

```
[1,3]
[5,8]
[10,12]
```

I'd like to query with a new Interval in the same domain:

```
new_interval = pd.Interval(2, 6, closed="both")
```

So something like this:

```
idx.get_loc(new_interval)

>> array([0, 1])
```

Is there a way to do this (aside from using an interval tree directly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `get_indexer`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.23.4'

In [2]: idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(1, 3), (5, 8), (10, 12)], closed='both')

In [3]: idx
Out[3]:
IntervalIndex([[1, 3], [5, 8], [10, 12]]
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[int64]')

In [4]: new_interval = pd.Interval(2, 6, closed='both')

In [5]: idx.get_indexer([new_interval])
Out[5]: array([0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Just to mention in case someone else encounters it: the indexed Intervals need to be unique for this to work!

Comment: A bit in the weeds, but for non-unique indexes you might have success with `_get_reindexer`, e.g. `idx._get_reindexer(pd.IntervalIndex([new_interval]))`.  I'd expect `get_indexer_non_unique` to work too, but looks to be broken currently.

Comment: Yeah it was a bit too problematic for my use case, too much working around certain limitations. I ended up just using an interval tree to begin with, which works seamlessly.